# Preparation of mesh for 3D printing

Tags: 3d-printing

I made a 3D model of a seal using Meshroom and thought I'd have a go at 3D printing it.  Is there an easy way in Blender to a. Identify what issues there are with the mesh in terms of 3D printing and b.  How to fix them.  I'm thinking of some kind of auto fix tool.  I've watched a few videos and it seems like it could be quite complicated so want to check if there is an easy fix before I investigate further.

[image]

Comment: There's a 3-D Print toolbox addon built in to Blender. Search for 'print' under Preferences > addons and check the Mesh: 3D-Print entry. I've never used Blender for 3D printing, but there's a video about the addon [here](: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XZgYtgTFDNk).

Comment: Also, depending on how close your model is to being ok, sometimes the printer slicer software itself can "fix" it the rest of the way